# How do I specify in a C program to run on a single core?

Tags: c, cpu-cores

I want to write a C program that will do the equivalent of "taskset --cpu-list 0 ./program args...". That is, the parent process and all the child processes created by fork() will run on a single core. I am reading up on sched-setaffinity(2), but according to the documentation, it assigns the process to a CPU affinity mask,i.e. processor, that could have multiple cores. (correct me if I am wrong please)
Is there a way?

Comment: No, `CPU(s)` is used synonym with `CPU Core(s)` here. Not a very exact language, agreed.

Comment: What OS? That's kind of important to know.

Comment: And by `CPU Core` we here mean "hardware-thread" in those cases where a `Core` does SMT or the like.  BTW: is there an accepted word for the hardware-that-provides-a-thread-of-control ?  Perhaps CPU... since, generally, we think of a (software) thread being allocated resources by the OS, including RAM, CPU, etc.  But if a Core is one or more CPUs, what do we call the thing which is one or more Cores ?  Perhaps Processor is a better name... so we have a CPU with one or more Cores each providing one or more Processors ?

Comment: I have an AMD Threadripper 2920X which is a CPU with 12 hyper-threaded cores gives you 24 processors. Each processor can be selected with setaffinity() - it will be on a single execution unit.

Comment: [Sources of taskset](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/schedutils/taskset.c#L128) are available online.